# osx: Delegating between a NSWindowController and a NSViewController

Tags: swift, macos, appdelegate, swift-protocols

Here is my problem simplified. I have a toolbar with a button in the Window and a label in the View. When the button is clicked I want to label.stringValue to go from "ON" to "OFF"

Here is the WindowController:

```
protocol ViewControllerDelegate {
    func switchOnOff()
}

class WindowController: NSWindowController {
    var viewDelegate: ViewControllerDelegate?
    @IBAction func pressedButton(_ sender: Any) {
        var vc = storyboard?.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "ViewController")) as? ViewController
        vc?.switchOnOff()
    }    
    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
    }
}
```

And here's the View Controller:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var onOffLabel: NSTextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let vc = WindowController()
        vc.viewDelegate = self    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: ViewControllerDelegate {
func switchOnOff() {
    if (onOffLabel.stringValue == "OFF" ) {
        onOffLabel.stringValue = "ON"
    } else {
        onOffLabel.stringValue = "OFF"
    }       
}
```

}

This is the storyboard:
[image]

When I click the button I get this error:

```
extension ViewController: ViewControllerDelegate {
    func switchOnOff() {
        if (onOffLabel.stringValue == "OFF" ) { // Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping 
        an Optional value
            onOffLabel.stringValue = "ON"
        } else {
            onOffLabel.stringValue = "OFF"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding: `var vc = storyboard?.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "ViewController")) as? ViewController`... Is the relevant scene indeed entitled 'ViewController'?

Comment: The storyboard ID = ViewController and the title in the attribute inspector == ViewController. Where can you find the name of the scene?

Comment: @Mitch Kroska – That sounds right (I don't really use Storyboards, so don't have much more to add, sorry!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this answer is not too late.

The way delegate works is that you tell the sender who to send to. The problem you have is that you created a new `WindowController` instance and registered as it's receiver. The problem is that the new instance of `WindowController` IS NOT the one that is sending the button click actions.

To make it work, you have to register your `ViewController` to the only instance of the `WindowController`.

Instead of doing

```
let vc = WindowController()
vc.viewDelegate = self
```

You need to find the actual Window Controller instance and register to that. Change the above code into:

```
(self.view.window?.windowController as! WindowController).delegate = self
```

And everything should work flawlessly.